# regex to find an uncommented println

Tags: regex, eclipse, find

Can someone share a regex that find all not double-slashed commented println in java code?

Example:

```
System.out.println("MATCH")   /*this line match*/
//    System.out.println("DOESN'T MATCH")  /*this line doesn't match*/
```

(I'm using this regex into throw eclipse searching dialog)

Comment: Regex is not the right tool. Consider: `/* LINEBREAKS System.out.println("DOESN'T MATCH") LINEBREAKS */`

Comment: You should probably tag the question `eclipse`, not `java` - it *may* use a different regex flavor, and probably use it in a different way.

Comment: @Bart Kiers : yes you are right. But i previously used a find and replace in this way: find all println and then replace with //println . So at least for this lines should work

Comment: Not to mention `/* // */ println` or `string s = "println"`. Oh, whole buckets of fun.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, as I already mentioned, regex is not the right tool, so if you end up using my suggestion, be sure to backup your source!

The following regex matches a single line that has `System.out.print` in it, `without` `//` or `/*` before it (in that same line!).

```
(?m)^((?!//|/\*).)*System\.out\.print.*
```

or simply:

```
(?m)^[ \t]*System\.out\.print.*
```

which can then be replaced with:

```
//$0
```

to comment it.

Again: this will go wrong with multi line comments, and as Kobi mentioned, stuff like `/* // */ System.out.print...` to name just two of the many cases this regex will trip over.

Also consider the line:

```
System.out.println("..."); /*
comments
*/
```

you don't want to end up with:

```
//System.out.println("..."); /*
comments
*/
```

Comment: @Bart Kiers: so have you any better tool to suggest to me?

Comment: @0verbose, yes, a proper Java parser.

Comment: @Bart Kiers: can you suggest me something to use inside eclipse ? thanks for your patience

Comment: @0verbose, no, I can't. If this is something you're going to do only once, try my regex-hack, backup your source and run all unit tests after replacing to see if you haven't broken anything. If this is something you're going to to on a regular basis (in which case my question would be: _"WHY?"_ :)), don't do this with a simple "search and replace".

Comment: @Bart Kiers: thank you for your regex-hack.. seems to work properly. I have the nasty habit to put println for debuggin purpouses.

Comment: @0verbose, you're welcome, and just be cautious. I recommend you to look into [Java's logging API](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/06/19/log.html): you then simply set a logging-level in a config file depending on how much information you want to log (to the screen, or to a file).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. As for the use case,

legacy JSP code with scriptlets that's a complete mess to try to debug with the debugger. You basically need printlines everywere.

Comment: How do I actually use the command? Do I put it in Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: @user2763361, the original question is about Eclipse's searching dialog. If you want to replace text from your terminal, checkout: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands

Answer (score -2):

You could probably just do something simple like:

```
^[ \t]*[^/][^/].*println.*
```