# Regex in Java interpreting a source.c file

Tags: java, regex

I have to recognize some characters in a .c file. For now I have to recognize the #define line but I would like to exclude the comments after the definition. For example:

```
#define KERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c) ((a)*65536+(b)*256+(c)) /* We're doing kernel work */
```

I have these results :

```
group1="KERNEL_VERSION"
group2="(a,b,c) ((a)*65536+(b)*256+(c)) /* We're doing kernel work */"
```

I would like to get rid of `/* We're doing kernel work */`

I have tried everything I just can't get rid of it. Here is where I am:

```
Pattern cdef = Pattern.compile("^#[\\t ]*define[\\t ]+(\\w+)[\\t ]*(.*)",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

I have tried adding `^[\\/\\*\\w+]`  or `[\\t ]+^\\/+\\*\\w*\\` ..... at the end of the string but either I lose all the second group or it does nothing

thanks a lot,

!!!! EDIT: I would like to find a way to eliminate a C comment so: /* comment */ from a pattern

EDIT 2: The way I see it I think it there should be a way to give the following istruction:
 "if you find "/*", don't take anything else, I am reading the file line by line so whatever is after the /* can be thrown away:

This is where I am treating the second group: "....(.*)"  So I have tried adding ^[\/\*] at the end of my string but it doesnt work and I lose the whole second part

Comment: I haven't the solution. Think is quite hard to achieve. I asked something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374843/regex-to-find-an-uncommented-println . Have a look.

Comment: thanks but it's not exactly the same because basically you are searching System.out... but what I am searching is /* xxxx */

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it. Just specify the comment at the end of your string. Like this:

```
(\\/\\*.*\\*\\/)
```

Complete test program:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern cdef = Pattern.compile("^#[\\t ]*define[\\t ]+(\\w+)[\\t ]*(.*)(\\/\\*.*\\*\\/)", Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matcher = cdef
                .matcher("#define KERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c) ((a)*65536+(b)*256+(c)) /* We're doing kernel work */");
        System.out.println(matcher.matches());
        for (int n = 0; n <= matcher.groupCount(); n++)
            System.out.println(matcher.group(n));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
true
#define KERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c) ((a)/65536+(b)/256+(c)) /* We're doing kernel work */
KERNEL_VERSION
(a,b,c) ((a)/65536+(b)/256+(c)) 
/* We're doing kernel work */
```

Comment: `/` has no special meaning in regexes, so you can write that as `(/\\*.*\\*/)`.  Never pass up a chance to avoid using backslashes in Java regexes. ;)

Comment: However, your regex *requires* a comment to be present.  I believe the OP wants to avoid consuming the comment if one is present.

Answer (score 0):

To me an easy way is to preprocess source sequence char-by-char and skip all between like:

```
// don't take all literally, pseudocode below
while(!EOF)
{
    // read next char
    ReadChar();

    // check for comment start
    if(prevChar == '/' && curChar == '*')
    {
        // remove '/' from output
        OutputContainer.RemoveLastChar();
        while(!(prevChar == '*' && curChar == '/'))
        {
            // skip next char
            SkipChar();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thks it's true that's the easy way or do a remove("xxx") but I would like to find a way in Regex as I am learning that.